# conditional rendering of components based on the user's authentication

Tags: next.js

I am currently working on a web application, and I have encountered an issue with the conditional rendering of components based on the user's authentication status. I have a Page component that should render either the NotLoggedHome component or the LoggedHome component depending on the user's state. However, I am experiencing a problem where both components are being rendered simultaneously, regardless of the user's authentication status. I have tried various approaches, including using state variables and conditional logic, but the issue persists. I need assistance in resolving this issue and ensuring that only the appropriate component is rendered based on the user's authentication status.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
"use client";

import RootLayout from "@/src/app/layout";
import Nav from "@/src/components/_common/Nav";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/src/context/AuthContext";
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IUser } from "@/src/interfaces/user";
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
import { getUserById } from "@/src/firebase/firestore/getData";
import { displayErrorToaster } from "@/src/components/_common/Toast";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import NotLoggedHome from "@/src/components/home/notLoggedHome";
import LoggedHome from "@/src/components/home/loggedHome";

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const authUser = useAuthContext();

  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);

  const fetchUser = useCallback((authUser: User) => {
    getUserById(authUser.uid)
      .then((r) => {
        setUser(r);
      })
      .catch(() => displayErrorToaster("Une erreur est survenue"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authUser) {
      fetchUser(authUser);
    }
  }, [router, authUser, fetchUser]);

  const navigation = [
    { name: "Home", href: "#", current: true },
    { name: "DashBoard", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Calendar", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Sign In", href: "/signin", current: false },
    { name: "Sign Up", href: "/signup", current: false },
  ];

  const loggedNavigation = [
    { name: "Home", href: "/", current: true },
    { name: "DashBoard", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Calendar", href: "#", current: false },
  ];

  return (
    <RootLayout>
      {user ? (
        <Nav navigation={loggedNavigation} imageUrl={user.imageUrl} />
      ) : (
        <Nav
          navigation={navigation}
          imageUrl={
            "default_url"
          }
        />
      )}
      {!user ? <NotLoggedHome /> : <LoggedHome user={user} />}
    </RootLayout>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution of my problem. I just wrap the user condition to loading state variable.

```
"use client";

import RootLayout from "@/src/app/layout";
import Nav from "@/src/components/_common/Nav";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/src/context/AuthContext";
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { IUser } from "@/src/interfaces/user";
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
import { getUserById } from "@/src/firebase/firestore/getData";
import { displayErrorToaster } from "@/src/components/_common/Toast";
import NotLoggedHome from "@/src/components/home/notLoggedHome";
import LoggedHome from "@/src/components/home/loggedHome";

const Page = () => {
  const authUser = useAuthContext();

  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const fetchUser = useCallback((authUser: User) => {
    getUserById(authUser.uid)
      .then((r) => {
        setUser(r);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(() => displayErrorToaster("Une erreur est survenue"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (authUser) {
      fetchUser(authUser);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [authUser, fetchUser]);

  const navigation = [
    { name: "Home", href: "#", current: true },
    { name: "DashBoard", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Calendar", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Sign In", href: "/signin", current: false },
    { name: "Sign Up", href: "/signup", current: false },
  ];

  const loggedNavigation = [
    { name: "Home", href: "/", current: true },
    { name: "Chat", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "DashBoard", href: "#", current: false },
    { name: "Calendar", href: "#", current: false },
  ];

  return (
    <RootLayout>
      {!loading ? (
        user ? (
          <>
            <Nav navigation={loggedNavigation} imageUrl={user.imageUrl} />
            <LoggedHome user={user} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Nav
              navigation={navigation}
              imageUrl={
                "defaulturl"
              }
            />
            <NotLoggedHome />
          </>
        )
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </RootLayout>
  );
};

export default Page;
```